# d3js update with div and attributes

Tags: d3.js

I am struggling with an update on d3js. The code below if uncommented does not update the values - actually, the initial layout disappears.
I cannot figure out yet. I just want the price to be updated.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*updated*

Someone (anonymous) updated http://jsfiddle.net/1qqdc0ns/11/ - so I am looking into this one.

I have cleaned my original version into http://jsfiddle.net/1qqdc0ns/12/ which still does not update properly.

```
function update(data) {
    console.log("update " + data);

    var quotes = d3.select("#quoteContainer")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data);

    // ENTER
    var q = quotes.enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "quotePanel");
    var m = q.append("div").attr("class", "carmodel");
    var p = q.append("div").attr("class", "price");
    var f1 = p.append("span").attr("class", "bigFigure");
    var f2 = p.append("span").attr("class", "smallFigure");

    f1.text(function (d) {
        var priceStr = d["price"].toString();
        var bigFigure = priceStr.substr(0, 4);
        console.log("bigFigure: " + bigFigure);
        return bigFigure;
    });
    f2.text(function (d) {
        return "00";
    });

    quotes.select("div").text(function (d) {
        var modelname = d["symbol"];
        console.log("Setting model name " + modelname);
        return modelname;
    });

    //quotes.exit().remove();
}

function onclick() {

    update([{
        "symbol": "BMW",
            "price": 9000
    }, {
        "symbol": "PIGEOT",
            "price": 124
    }]);

};

d3.select('#update')
    .on("click", onclick);

update([{
    "symbol": "ASTON",
        "price": 3000
}, {
    "symbol": "MARTIN",
        "price": 6500
}]);
```

Comment: The data selection handles each instance of your data so you don't need the each; you simply assign the attr on update. If you add a plunker or fiddle we can help. You might want to look again at the general update pattern for d3.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I have read and done a few created/updates with d3js, but it is the first time I am trying to do it with a "complex" attribute/div. The fiddle is there http://jsfiddle.net/1qqdc0ns/10/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1qqdc0ns/13/  I can only partially update... the model names. But on creation it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Igor.
The solution is:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ihorad/1qqdc0ns/14/

```
function update(data) {
    var quotes = d3.select("#quoteContainer")
        .selectAll(".quotePanel")
        .data(data);

    var q = quotes.enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "quotePanel"); 
    var m = q.append("div").attr("class", "carmodel");
    var p = q.append("div").attr("class", "price");
    var f1 = p.append("span").attr("class", "bigFigure");
    var f2 = p.append("span").attr("class", "smallFigure");

    quotes.select(".carmodel").text(function (d) {
        var modelname = d["symbol"];
        return modelname;
    });
    quotes.select(".bigFigure").text(function (d) {
        var priceStr = d["price"].toString();
        var bigFigure = priceStr.substr(0, 4);
        return bigFigure;
    });
    quotes.select(".smallFigure").text(function (d) {
        return "00";
    });

    quotes.exit().remove();
}
```